# QNEAT3 Execution failed

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, network-analyst, isochrone

I've been attempting to run a number of different processes within the QNEAT3 toolbox, however I keep on getting an error similar to the one seen in the image below:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users/urban/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\algs\IsoAreaAsPolygonsFromLayer.py", line 225, in processAlgorithm
> input_coordinates = getListOfPoints(startPoints)
> File "C:\Users/urban/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QNEAT3\Qneat3Utilities.py", line 90, in getListOfPoints
> expected_geom_type = QgsWkbTypes.displayString(1) #Point
> TypeError: QgsWkbTypes.displayString(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
> Execution failed after 0.05 seconds

[image]

I've installed matplotlib, pip and I've also uninstalled and reinstalled the QNEAT3 plugin multiple times, however nothing has been able to change the error.

Has anyone else run into this sort of error while using QNEAT3? Curious to see if anyone has any resolutions or any tips on how I could solve this issue.

Comment: Did you try to start with a new user profile? Settings->User Profiles...->New Profile

Comment: Yep. Just tried that and nothing resolved

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error was because I was running QGIS V3.31-Master. I switched back to V3.28.4 to check if it would work with a more stable version and it did!